# Take a random value from an intMap in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I'm having a little trouble writing a function that simulates the roll of a dice. 
Said dice has 6 sides, with 1-5 and W on it.
1 is worth 1 point, 2 is worth 2 points and so on. But W is worth 5 points.
I made a data type Side, with a Char value, and an Int points. I generate an intMap where I save all six sides, and then I use a function rollDice, which should return a random side.

Like so:

```
module Dice where

import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import System.Random


data Side = Side {
            value :: Char, 
            points :: Int
            } deriving Show



data Dice = Dice (IM.IntMap (Side))

dice = Dice $ IM.fromList[(0,Side '1' 1),(1,Side '2' 2),
                                        (2 ,Side '3' 3),(3,Side '4' 4),
                                        (4,Side '5' 5),(5,Side 'W' 5)]



throwDice :: Dice -> Side
throwDice (Dice (intMap)) = intMap IM.!(randomRIO (1,6 :: Int))
```

Which returns the following error on trying to load:

```
Dice.hs:22:41:
    Couldn't match expected type `IM.Key' with actual type `IO a0'
    In the return type of a call of `randomRIO'
    In the second argument of `(IM.!)', namely
      `(randomRIO (1, 6 :: Int))'
    In the expression: intMap IM.! (randomRIO (1, 6 :: Int))
```

I've read somewhere that you should only user RandomRIO inside an IO monad, but I need to append the thrown side to a list and then display all the values of the sides in that list, and I'm completely lost at how to convert the output of the RandomRIO function to a useable format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, programming in IO monad may be frustrating for a novice, but there's no way out of it. You could use another monad, like State, but it's still a monad you have to deal with. It's not a limitation, it's natural and correct that a pure function can't be non-deterministic.

Comment: There is `unsafePerformIO` which can help you to fool the compiler, but using it in this case will certainly mess the program up.

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` is not for "fooling the compiler".

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It does not fit the situation anyway.

Comment: You have keys `0,1,2,3,4,5`. The appropriate data structure for a lookup table in that case is an _array_. (Note: your lookups suppose keys from 1 to 6, one of the two should be adapted.) You should separate getting a random index from the lookup in the table. For knowing what the proper way to do it is, we need to know what you're actually trying to do. Using `randomRIO` is almost always a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`randomRIO` has type `Random a => (a, a) -> IO a`, it means that the result value is trapped to IO monad. The IO monad can't be escaped, so if you want to use random values, your function must return a value of IO-bound type also (if same inputs do not produce the same output, function just can not be pure).

I hope something like

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random 

main = do
    randList <- replicateM yourListSize (randomRIO (1,6))
    print randList
```

will help you to start.